# Why is my animation not playing?

Tags: html, css

I've followed a short tutorial to create a bouncing arrow however the code I've used it pretty much the same excluding small differences.

However, when I add it to my hero unit, it doesn't play my animation.

It could be the `transform` or `keyframe` mixins I used...

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9hxfusa/

Comment: Are you referring to this animation: http://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp ?

Comment: Yeah that animation, I've got the near exact code and it still doesn't work

Comment: did you forget to include @import "compass/css3" at the beginning?

Comment: I'm not using compass, there must be an easier way to do it without downloading the entire compass library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `keyframes` & `mixins` declarations at the top. You have to declare them before calling them.

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpqgEy)

Comment: it's not just the keyframes its also the mixins

Comment: Correct. Mixins act as variables that need to be defined beforehand. See updated answer.

Comment: funny thing, I tried doing this about 30 minutes ago and it wasn't working, because I forgot to refresh my browser. Well the struggle got me to come up with a simpler solution based on the code, I hope the OP benefits from both our answers

Comment: Your original code was correct. I just reorganized it and made sure compass was being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked and simplified your code, I think you can arrange the animation itself to be smoother, up to your liking. Remember to add cross browser support or at least use SCSS to manage it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/Ltjehe8q/)

CSS

```
body { background-color: black; }

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%       { bottom:5px; }
    25%, 75% { bottom:15px; }
    50%      { bottom:20px; }
    100%     { bottom:0; }
}
```

I also think the key issue is with the mixins, however I stirred away from it to find a simpler solution for you.

Edit: I tried doing the following initially but I missed refreshing my jsFiddle and missed the obvious solution, which is now highlighted by @Oriol. Anyways, the issue is that your keyframe & mixin code is being positioned after the animation code (or at the top of your CSS for simplicity's sake). If you wish to keep your code as is just do that, or you can try my simplified solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare

```
@mixin transform($transforms) {
-moz-transform: $transforms;
-o-transform: $transforms;
-ms-transform: $transforms;
-webkit-transform: $transforms;
transform: $transforms;
}

@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
  @content;
}
@-moz-keyframes $animation-name {
  @content;
}  
@-ms-keyframes $animation-name {
  @content;
}
@-o-keyframes $animation-name {
  @content;
}  
@keyframes $animation-name {
  @content;
}
}

@mixin animation($str) {
 -webkit-animation: #{$str};
 -moz-animation: #{$str};
 -ms-animation: #{$str};
 -o-animation: #{$str};
 animation: #{$str};      
}
```

before include keyframes and transform. You must also set the bounce class in a different way (remove ''):

```
.bounce {
  @include animation(bounce 2s infinite);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uth333cg/